# Cannot Open Google App Maker samples

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I am new to Google App Maker and I want to explore some sample apps. But I cannot even open sample apps that require access to Google Cloud SQL.

I've set up Cloud SQL for other projects already. How to enable Cloud SQL for a project that cannot be opened?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I need to set up the default Cloud SQL instance for the samples to work.

Here is how I did it: https://medium.com/@wangyidan621/how-to-setup-default-google-cloud-sql-for-google-app-maker-ca978acffbc6